# issue with uploading heavy files above 5MB

Tags: php, file-upload

```
 if(trim($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$j]) != "")
            {

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$j],"../../../../uploads/msg_attachment/".time()."_".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$j]);



            }
```

upload_max_filesize 128M
max_file_uploads    20

Getting no error .Please help

Comment: And you have of course turned on error_reporting ?

Comment: also change post_max_size = "128M"

Comment: Check out these: [upload-large-files-in-php](https://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/)

Comment: Check the file/directory permission. Print the files complete route and check if directory exists and the permissions are ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think Brijal Savaliya is right, you change the POST_MAX_SIZE along with MAX_EXECUTION_TIME etc to higher values, you can do this by two ways...

- Use PHP Code
- Change PHP.ini

**By PHP Code**

```
//You can write a code to change this value by function
ini_set('POST_MAX_SIZE',128M);
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME ',300);
```

**Edit in PHP.ini file**

```
POST_MAX_SIZE = 128M
MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 300
```